# Return list of resources from directory search

Tags: java, spring, file, nio

I have the following code which looks for files that satisfies the patterns provided as parameters. I am trying to return a `List` of `org.springframework.core.io.Resource;`

```
public class FileManager {
    public List<Resource> getInputFileList(String sourcePath, String fileNamePattern, String suffix, String fileDate) throws IOException {
        List<Resource> files = new ArrayList<>();
        Path directoryPath = Paths.get(sourcePath);

        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.find(directoryPath, 1,
                (path, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile()
                        && path.getFileName().startsWith(fileNamePattern)
                        && path.getFileName().toString().contains(fileDate)
                        && path.toString().endsWith(suffix))) {
            paths.forEach(e -> files.add(e));
        }

        return files;
    }
}
```

Is the best approach to apply a cast

```
paths.forEach(e -> files.add((Resource) e));
```

or is there another way of doing this? i.e. use `PathResource` ?

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @IQV im unsure if I should apply a cast or there is better alternative. Question updated